# Swapping Css stylesheets

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created two buttons and I am able to change my stylesheet once I click on these buttons. However when I go to the next page on my website the stylesheet reverts back to the original and does not stay how the user set it. I was wondering how this would be tackled...

Answer (score 1):

Store preferred style in a cookie or localStorage.

If you use a cookie then you can set proper one at server which would prevent style flash.

Alternatively use script when page loads to read cookie or localStorage and append preferred stylesheet to `<head>` accordingly

Both methods are easy to research